# Is there a half-open TCP connection limit in Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, tcp

Or at least, is it a low limit like 10 or 50?

It was present since XP SP2 (I think), and was finally cancelled (= I think now the user can set the limit manually) in Vista SP2. What is the current state, or at least planned for RTM, with Win 7? How "crackable" is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This article may be [useful reference](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/06/07/half-open-outbound-tcp-connections-limit-removed-in-windows-7-and-vista-sp2-no-patch-required/).

> Microsoft appears to have a change of heart on the half-open outbound TCP connection attempts limit with the release of Windows Vista SP2 and Windows 7, probably due to the fact that the limit never effective in stopping the spreading of worms and viruses, or Microsoft has grown more confident about security feature of newer operating system.
>   ...
>   Half-open TCP connections limit is not implemented in Windows 7 since Windows 7 Beta release.

Another article from the same blog describes their [TCP-Z half-open patching utility](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/12/31/tcp-z-free-download-half-open-tcpip-memory-patcher-for-x86-and-x64-windows-7-vista-and-xp/).
However, I will note that i never felt comfortable patching 3rd party things into Windows system files.

---

Some more older conversation at the [Microsoft connect site](http://connect.microsoft.com/WNDP/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=313447).